# How to see if a user has already registered

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have been learning PHP etc. but the thing is, I can register many times with the same name and IP.

This is the code of my register.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Gebruikerspaneel
</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'connect.php';
?>
<?php
include 'functions.php';
?>
<?php
include 'titelbar.php';
?>

<h3>Registreer hier</h3>

<form method='post'>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $gebruikersnaam = $_POST['gebruikersnaam'];
    $wachtwoord = md5($_POST['wachtwoord']);
    if(empty($gebruikersnaam) or empty($wachtwoord)){
        echo "<p>Gelieve alles in te vullen!</p>";
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO gebruikers VALUES('', '$gebruikersnaam', '$wachtwoord', '2', 'a')");
        echo "<p>U bent succesvol geregistreerd!</p>";
    }
}
?>
Gebruikersnaam:<br />
<input type='text' name='gebruikersnaam' />
<br /><br />
Wachtwoord:<br />
<input type='password' name='wachtwoord' />
<br /><br />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Registreren' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I make it so you get an error and your information isn't sent to the database?

I am Dutch, so some things are in Dutch.

Comment: where are you checking the database to see if the username already exists in the database?

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: You can use something to the affect of `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { echo "Exists"; }`

Comment: You should name your variables in English, this gives other developers a better opportunity understanding your code. (Even if it's clear here.) Also `md5` isn't the best way to go for password hashing, you should use `password_hash` and `password_verify` instead.

Comment: I don't have problem with Dutch.. but you also want to limit the maximal number of chars in the function md5 so your server won't be an target for crypto based DoSS (by posting lots off 8Mb sized passwords..) and indeed you should use an salt or even beter php bcrypt (designd to be slow on GPU's beter against bruteforce attacks) function

Comment: @RaymondNijland md5 is designed to be very, very fast, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Recode  It is not recommended to use md5 to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm.... http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash... GPU can force around +1.5 M/s so an 6 wide plaintext a-z A-Z 0-9 is bruteforced within 10-20 seconds..

Comment: @RaymondNijland That´s what I said 4 comments above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic dictated u need to check if user exists before u insert him. u can do it by:

1. putting a unique key on the username, and capture the duplicate entry error code
2. Query the DB before the insert, if the user is already there.

I am not touching many other issues you have, concentrate on one point at a time.

Comment: +1 Indeed catch 1062 error number in PHP let the database handle unique problem like it should..

Answer (score -1):

Two things you can do:

1. Check if the username already exists with something like this:

   `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = $username;`

   If the result is greater than 0, show an error message.
2. Add a unique key constraint on the username column using MySQL Workbench or the command line, whichever you are using. This acts as a safeguard to prevent duplication in the database if the code should prevent duplication for some reason.

**Big side note:**

Research parameterization of SQL queries, because right now, you have a huge security flaw happening, called [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Comment: Why the down vote, whoever it was?

Comment: They did it to my answer too, I just deleted it and re-posted. Got a more reasonable vote now.